# XSL Catch all Navigation Composed of Children or Siblings of Specific Parent Node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I hope someone will be able to help me with this I've been wracking my brain trying to figure it out - reading through stackoverflow for the better part of today and yesterday trying things but its not just there yet.

Here's my xml its generated from a cms.

```
<Navigation Type="Children" Name="LeftNavigation" label="Left Navigation">
      <Page ID="x13" URL="x13.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="Cars" />
        <Page ID="x12" URL="x12.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-1">
        <Page ID="x27" URL="x27.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-2" />
        <Page ID="x28" URL="x28.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-3" />
        <Page ID="x31" URL="x31.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-4" />
      </Page>
      -
      <Page ID="x14" URL="x14.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="Books">
        <Page ID="x32" URL="x32.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-2" />
        <Page ID="x33" URL="x33.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-3" />
        <Page ID="x34" URL="x34.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-4" />
        <Page ID="x35" URL="x35.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-5" />
        <Page ID="x36" URL="x36.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-6" />
        <Page ID="x37" URL="x37.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-7" />
        <Page ID="x38" URL="x38.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-8" />
        <Page ID="x39" URL="x39.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-9" />
        <Page ID="x40" URL="x40.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-10" />
        <Page ID="x41" URL="x41.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-11" />
      </Page>
      <Page ID="x15" URL="x15.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="Clothes" />
      -
      <Page ID="x47" URL="x47.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us" CategoryIds="" Name="Toys">
        <Page ID="x49" URL="x49.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us"  CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-1" />
        <Page ID="x48" URL="x48.xml" Schema="ContentPage" Locale="en-us"  CategoryIds="" Name="subsection-2" />
      </Page>
    </Navigation>
```

What I'm trying to do with this is to create a left navigation that only lists its children or siblings of that parent.

So I've been trying out something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentPage">
    <xsl:value-of select="//ContentPage/@ID"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

First I made a variable that would find out where I was and get the attribute ID.

```
<xsl:template name="navigation">
    <ul id="oc-left-nav">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//@ID='$currentPage' | parent::()" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

So this part is my attempt at saying: select the Page with an ID that is equal to my variable or if you're a sibling then list all the siblings under that parent. But as you can see I don't know how to write that.

```
  <xsl:template match="//@ID[.='$currentPage'] | parent::()">
    <xsl:for-each select="Page">
      <li class="oc-navlink">
        <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="@URL"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
        </a>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

At the end of the day I need a dynamic list of all the children relative to what Parent page you're a descendant of. Well here's hoping. I'll keep plugging away at it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what you are trying to do, but I can certainly make a few observations for you:

You say "So this part is my attempt at saying: select the Page..."

followed by a template match which returns @ID nodes ...

xsl:template match="//@ID ..

Doing a for-each over child "Page" elements of "@ID" attributes will certainly return nothing. The "@ID" attribute has no child.

Second, you set the value of the variable currentPage to //ContentPage/@ID. I do not even see the element ContentPage in your sample XML. This variable would be empty unless you are not showing all the relevant stuff here.

I think I know what you want for output but perhaps you can post what you expect to get so we don't have to guess.